# Spinors and Tensors: what is the form of spin transformation matrix?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, differential-geometry, group-theory, spinors

The (covariant) vector transformation law is given by:

> $$V^{'}_{\mu} = t^{\nu}\hspace{0.1mm}_{\mu'}V_{\nu} =\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\mu}}V_{\nu} \tag{1}$$

where the transformation is given by a set of equations $x'^{\mu} = f(x^{\nu})$ and the inverse of the jacobian matrix $t^{\nu}\hspace{0.1mm}_{\mu'}=\Big(\frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\Big)^{-1}:=\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\mu}}$. Therefore, the *form* ofthe matrices $t^{\nu}\hspace{0.1mm}_{\mu'}$ are the Jacobian matrices.

Now, one form of think about spinors is given by $[1],[2],[3]$; this form is highly chart-dependent.

> $$\psi^{'}_{A} = t^{B}\hspace{0.1mm}_{A'}\psi _{B}  \tag{2}$$

I would like to know, what are the form of matrices $t^{B}\hspace{0.1mm}_{A'}$?

$$* * *$$

$[1]$ CORSON.E.M. *Introduction to Tensors, Spinors, and Relativistic Wave-Equations*.

$[2]$ PLEBANSKI.J. *An Introduction to General Relativity and Cosmology*.

$[3]$ O'DONNELL.P. *Introduction to 2-Spinors in General Relativity*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinor representations only exist in Euclidean or in Minkowski-spaces, but not in spaces that need more general coordinates like curved spaces.
Nevertheless one can use local  Minkowski frames which can be constructed by so-called tetrades $e^a_\mu(x)$. So a vector whose general coordinates are numerated by a  Greek index $\mu$ for instance can be transformed into a local Minkowski frame  whose coordinates are numerated by a Latin index $a$:

$V^a = e^a_\mu(x) V^\mu$

The spinors only live in the local Minkowski frames. The transformation group which governs the transformation rules here is the Lorentz group. So vectors in this frame transform according to Lorentz-transformations:

$V^a = \Lambda^a_{\,b} V^b$

Besides 4-vectors spinors can also exist since the Lorentz-group does have two-valued spinor representations. In your post the type of spinor is not given, so it could actually be a Weyl-spinor, Majorana-spinor or a Dirac-spinor. While Majorana- and Dirac-spinors transform according to reducible representations of the Lorentz-group Weyl-spinors transform according to the irreducible fundamental spinor representation of the Lorentz-group. In order to be complete, 2 types of fundamental spinor representations actually  exist which are distinguished by the index notation. The "first" one has indices without dot, the second one is marked by dotted indices. Once the first representation $(\mathbf{v},\vec{\alpha})\rightarrow A$ is known, the second is the complex-conjugated to the first one: $(\mathbf{v},\vec{\alpha})\rightarrow A^\ast$. This second representation is not equivalent to the first one.

The fundamental spin representation matrices $A\in SL(2,\mathbf{C})$ form the group of $2x2$ unimodular matrices, i.e. $det(A)=1$. These matrices are not unitarian, if they were only one type of spin-representation would exist. That is actually the case if the transformations are limited to the rotation group, in that special case $A\in SU(2)$.

Finally, as the representation theory of the Lorentz-group is well-known I can even provide the form of the  (undotted)  spin-representation:

$$ A = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{u}\vec{\sigma}) \exp(-\frac{i}{2}\vec{\alpha}\vec{\sigma})$$

where $\vec{\sigma}$ are the Pauli-matrices, $\vec{\alpha}$ the rotation vector and  $\mathbf{u} = artanh(v)R(\vec{\alpha})\frac{\mathbf{v}}{v}\quad  v=|\mathbf{v}|$.
$\alpha$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are the 6 parameters that parametrize the Lorentz-group
(rotations combined with boosts).

Final remark: The matrices $A$ transform contravariant spinors:

$\Psi'^a = A^a_{\, b} \Psi^b$

whereas spinors with covariant indices transform according to the contra-gredient matrix $A^{-1\,T}$ (That is the same as with 4-vectors which transform either according to the standard Lorentz-transformation or the contra-gradient one if they have covariant indices).
The contra-gradient spin representation is equivalent to $A$, i.e. it exists a matrix $S$ with  $A^{-1\,T} = SAS^{-1}$:

$$\Phi' = A^{-1\,T} \Phi \quad\quad \text{with indices} \quad\quad \Phi'_a = A_a^{\,b} \Phi_b$$